# Lottie Animation Android issue with frame size

Tags: android, kotlin, lottie

We have used Lottie for showing onboarding animation and it renders differently on iOS and Android.

iOS is the way that is desired:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Mp4gGCrNuW2s23qeMClui8sCqemgb1wd

How it looks on Android:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KrWH6DHYDnDIl9AGSgPheLNKzftGcoo0

When we view the animation on lottiefiles.com, it looks like the Android version.
My Lottie animation view looks like this.

```
<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
            android:id="@+id/animation_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            app:lottie_autoPlay="false"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:lottie_scale="0.1"
            app:lottie_loop="false"
            app:lottie_progress="0"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            />
```

Does anyone know how I can change the aspect ratio on android for the animation?

Answer (score 3):

Do not use scaleType

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

Answer (score 0):

We changed the animation file itself to fix the issue and works like a charm now.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use multiple other ways like setting XML bounds, scaling the `LottieAnimationView` or using `scaleType` attribute.